# javascript - Stop Video From Playing When Modal Closes Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm newbie to javascript using bootstrap Modal, but I'm not sure how to stop my youtube video when I push the close button or the close icon.

Can someone explain how I can get my video to stop playing ?

here is my code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
               </div>
                 <div class="modal-body" id="video">
                     'VIDEO URL HERE'
                            </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and my Javascript here :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  jQuery('#myModal video').attr("src", jQuery("#myModal  video").attr("src"));
});
</script>
```

any help and suggestion will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You should enable the youtube api in your `<iframe>` tag:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZrXbX8cWrvQ?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
```

I added `?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer` as query string in the `src` attribute and also added the attribute `allowscriptaccess="always"`.

After that, you will be able to use the `stopVideo` function:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var iframeElement = $(this).find('iframe')[0];
    var action = { event: 'command', func: 'stopVideo', args: '' };
    iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(action), '*');
});
```

Here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpwn5sw4/).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it's not working :/ , video still continues to play in background.

Comment: When you try: `console.log(videoElement);` Does it find your video? Does your video tag have some id or class?

Comment: i'm getting youtube video using `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: Try replacing `pause` with `stopVideo`

Comment: Note I also changed `.find('video')` to `.find('iframe')`

Comment: should I copy, paste the exact code or i have to change something ? cause it's still not woking in my case :/ :(

Comment: Strange, just copy and paste should work. Have you tried: `console.log(iframeElement)`? Last try: replace `$(this)` to `$('#myModal')`

Comment: what should be the output of `console.log(iframeElement); ` it gives nothing.

Comment: It should find your `<iframe>` tag. Does your tag have some id or class?

Comment: my js
`<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {

       $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    var iframeElement = $('#myModal').find('iframe')[0];

    iframeElement.stopVideo();

    });

  });

</script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127741/discussion-between-guedes-and-user26).

Comment: @User26. I got an working jsfiddle and updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BWPfY8PiYagfb1zIHUEV?p=preview) code will help you, like it helped me.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Autostop Videos in Closed Modal</title>

    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Autostop Videos in Closed Modal</h1>

    <ul class="nav" >
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video1">Video 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video2">Video 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="modal fade" id="video1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video 1</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/108792063" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="video2">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video 2</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/69593757" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $iframe = $(this).find("iframe");
    $iframe.attr("src", $iframe.attr("src"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an onClick action in your close button as below.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="document.getElementById('video').pause();">Close</button>
```

And remember to change `'video'` to your own `#videoID`.